# c# looping through list to pass data to SendGrid template

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, foreach, sendgrid

I am working on an order confirmation to be sent via SendGrid, using a template. Where I am struggling is in generating the JSON and passing it on to the template in SendGrid. Any help is appreciated.

My controller:

```
    var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SGAPIkey"];
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var msg = new SendGridMessage();
    msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("orders@freshNclean.ch", "freshNclean"));
    msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(UserManager.FindById(userID).Email));
    msg.SetTemplateId("d-9f76f10c08964219954067b31b3a97ad");

    var orderedLineItems = DATADB.LineItemList.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == orderID).ToList();

    string prd;
    int qty;
    decimal prc;
    foreach (var item in orderedLineItems)
    {
        if (item.SubscriptionQuantity == 0)
        {
            prd = item.ProductName;
            qty = item.SingleOrderQuantity;
            prc = item.SingleOrderPrice;
        }
        else
        {
            prd = item.ProductName;
            qty = item.SubscriptionQuantity;
            prc = item.SubscriptionPrice;
        }
        var body = new orderConfirmation
        {
            receipt = true,
            lineItem = new lineItem
            {
                product = prd,
                quantity = qty,
                //price = prc
            },
            total = "CHF " + order.OrderAmount.ToString(),
            company = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressCompanyName).First(),
            name = UserManager.FindById(userID).FirstName.ToString() + " " + UserManager.FindById(userID).LastName.ToString(),
            address01 = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressStreet).First() + " " + DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressNumber).First(),
            address02 = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressAdditional).First(),
            zip = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressZIP).First(),
            city = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressCity).First(),
            state = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressState).First(),
            instructions = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingInstructions).First()
        };
        msg.SetTemplateData(body);
    };
    var response = /*await*/ client.SendEmailAsync(msg);


private class orderConfirmation
    {
        [JsonProperty("subject")]
        public string subject { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("receipt")]
        public bool receipt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("company")]
        public string company { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("address01")]
        public string address01 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("address02")]
        public string address02 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("zip")]
        public string zip { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string city { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public string state { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("instructions")]
        public string instructions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lineItem")]
        public lineItem lineItem { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("total")]
        public string total { get; set; }
    }
    private class lineItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("product")]
        public string product { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }
```

And the code on the SendGrid template looks as follows:

```
{{#each lineItem}}



<tr>



  <td style="width:500px;max-width:85%;"><div style="text-align: left;color:#000e56">{{lineItem.product}}</div></td>

  <td style="width:30px;max-width:4.5%;"><div style="text-align: right;color:#000e56">{{lineItem.quantity}}x</div></td>

  <td style="width:70px;max-width:15.5%;"><div style="text-align: right;color:#000e56">CHF {{lineItem.price}}</div></td>

</tr>



{{/each}}
```

My problem is that I do not get all of the line items in the template, but instead I get 3 times the same line item listed. From what I have figured out by testing around, is that this is likely related to the 3 values that I am trying to pass over per line item (product, quantity, price). Any advice on where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting *TemplateData* to only last order, you should assign list of *orderConfirmation* to it,so Replace foreach loop with below code:

```
var allLines=new List<orderConfirmation>();
foreach (var item in orderedLineItems)
{
    if (item.SubscriptionQuantity == 0)
    {
        prd = item.ProductName;
        qty = item.SingleOrderQuantity;
        prc = item.SingleOrderPrice;
    }
    else
    {
        prd = item.ProductName;
        qty = item.SubscriptionQuantity;
        prc = item.SubscriptionPrice;
    }
    var body = new orderConfirmation
    {
        receipt = true,
        lineItem = new lineItem
        {
            product = prd,
            quantity = qty,
            //price = prc
        },
        total = "CHF " + order.OrderAmount.ToString(),
        company = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressCompanyName).First(),
        name = UserManager.FindById(userID).FirstName.ToString() + " " + UserManager.FindById(userID).LastName.ToString(),
        address01 = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressStreet).First() + " " + DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressNumber).First(),
        address02 = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressAdditional).First(),
        zip = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressZIP).First(),
        city = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressCity).First(),
        state = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingAddressState).First(),
        instructions = DATADB.ShippingAddressList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).Where(x => x.IsDefaultShippingAddress == true).Select(x => x.ShippingInstructions).First()
    };
  allLines.Add(body);
};
msg.SetTemplateData(allLines);
```

Comment: thx @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi - just tried it out, and it does make sense. However, now I find myself in a situation where the email is not being sent anymore.. and I have no idea where it got stuck...

Comment: can you debug your code and set break point on email sending?

Comment: just did that, from looking at it, all the required data is included, but it just did not seem to arrive at SendGrid (no email triggered at all) - any advice?

Comment: it loops through the list perfectly and the number of times i have items.. so that is certainly good, allLines also shows the correct count (= number of items ordered) and that gets passed on to msg where I can see that the Personalization is showing count 2 (in line with the number of line items). Still, the email does not arrive.

Comment: response is showing Id 3131, status waiting for activation

Comment: Seems like an email sending problem, maybe using await can solve problem or email configuration is wrong

Comment: tried that too, response is now showing StatusCode BadRequest and email still not getting through

Comment: if I go back to my initial code, but include the await on sending, it would work again, but also put me back on square one...

Comment: change it to  var response = /*await*/ client.SendEmailAsync("test"); and see if it sens email

Comment: Send test email with appropriate parameters and see if it works .SendMailAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportEmailAddr"], 
                                    message.Destination, 
                                    message.Subject, 
                                    message.Body);

Comment: that gives me other errors.. but the point is that the sending of a message per se is working fine, even in the initial code, an email would be sent, just with the wrong data in it (3 times the same item instead of x times the right items). From what I can tell this all breaks somehow with the code you provided.. it looks like the right data is included but for some reason the email is not being sent..

Comment: Sorry i have no idea, if you create another question about sending email in your code hopefully people can help you

Comment: Thx anyways Mehrdad